# Sequelize How to save model with hasMany association?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have two model Job and Contact. A Job can have many Contact. Here is the modal.

Job

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Job = sequelize.define("Job", {
    job_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    due_date: DataTypes.DATE,
    assigned_hours: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    descriptions: DataTypes.STRING
  });
  Job.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    Job.hasMany(models.Contact, { foreignKey: "job_id" });
  };
  return Job;
};
```

Contact

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Contact = sequelize.define(
    "Contact",
    {
      organization_name: DataTypes.STRING,
      contact_person: DataTypes.STRING,
      email: DataTypes.STRING,
      phone: DataTypes.STRING,
      // Group can only be either client,contact or contractor
      group: DataTypes.STRING,
      sub_group: DataTypes.STRING,
      instruction: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    {}
  );

  return Contact;
};
```

In my application, contact is created separately and user just selects the contact while creating job. So, what should I do to associate already created contact with job? I have read the docs but I can't get a clear picture. Should I do something like `newJob.setContacts`. Do I need to pass whole object of contact or just the id of the contact ( `newJob.setContacts(['1','2']`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for one, your contact model does not actually even have the foreign key column you used for the hasMany... job_id... is this actually a many to many relationship you mean to be using? Can a job have many contacts and a contact belong to multiple jobs???

Comment: The you should have an Id column for both tables and a join table in your database... the join table should consist of the id’s of both records..Then you must model that join table, and include the model name in a belongsToMany relationship on both the Job and Contact models

Comment: Give it a shot and if you need a hand post the code for what you are trying back in here and I’ll help out